# FTPClient cannot resolve host even with internet permission

Tags: java, android, ftp, ftp-client

I've added the correct permission into my `AndroidManifest.XML` file to enable me connect to the internet from my app

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.my_test_app">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".LogOn"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ftpDetails"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

But, when trying to establish an FTP connection like so

```
FTPClient FtpClient = new FTPClient();

FtpClient.connect(ftpServer + ftpFolder); // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
FtpClient.login(ftpUser, ftpPass);

int reply = FtpClient.getReplyCode();
```

The error occurs on `FtpClient.connect(ftpServer + ftpFolder);`

The values in the variables are in the format of

```
ftpServer = ftp://ftp.myServer.co.uk/mySite.co.uk/
ftpFolder = My Folder (Test)
```

I can get to this folder through Windows File Explorer on my PC so I know it's a valid path, but when testing in the app I get the following error

> Unable to resolve host "ftp://ftp.myServer.co.uk/mySite.co.uk/My Folder": No address associated with hostname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument of `FTPClient.connect` method (or actually the inherited [`SocketClient.connect`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/SocketClient.html#connect(java.lang.String)) is `hostname`, not URL.

So it should be:

```
ftpServer = "ftp.myServer.co.uk";
```